# Lightning app page is not accessible from partner community user

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-apps, partner-communities, lightning-components, lightning-app-builder

I made a lightning app page and placed my lightning component on it. It works perfect as an admin user, but when I login as a partner community user, that app page is not accessible. We are using Partner Central Template for partner community. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hi @user3304637 did you get an answer for this? i'm facing a similar situation